# New line doesn't seem to work. php

Tags: php, file, newline

I've test.php which contains:

```
function tailShell($filepath, $lines = 1) {
        ob_start();
        passthru('tail -'  . $lines . ' ' . escapeshellarg($filepath));
        return trim(ob_get_clean());
    }
    $test = tailShell('som.log',3);
    echo $test;
```

som.log contains

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

When i'm using it, php prints text like that ***6 5 4 3 2*** without new line, how to fix this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're displaying it in an HTML context (in a browser) it's normal for it to do that because HTML collapses white space, including line breaks. Wrap your output in `<pre>` tags to retain the line breaks.

```
function tailShell($filepath, $lines = 1) {
    ob_start();
    passthru('tail -'  . $lines . ' ' . escapeshellarg($filepath));
    return trim(ob_get_clean());
}
$test = tailShell('som.log',3);
echo '<pre>'. $test .'</pre>';
```